# Why podman stats and systemd status show different memory usage?

Tags: systemd, services, podman

Initially, I tried to avoid memory leaks of lxml with spawning multiprocesses and terminate it but I failed.

So before I try a new idea, I set `OOMPolicy=stop`, `MemoryMax=2G` in the service file.

My intention is that if the memory usage in podman stats hits 2G, systemd's OOM-killer sends stop(instead of SIGKILL from kernel.). So it will be restarted.

However, memory usage in `podman stats` is `164.9MB`, but `systemctl status` result is `Memory: 756.0K (high: 1.8G max: 2.0G available: 1.8G)`.(you may ignore high. I just tried with `--runtime`.)

Of course, the experiment will show something but I want to hear an explanation about memory.. Because unix will have the reason for the behavior that I just don't understand yet.

```
$podman stats

ID            NAME                                              CPU %       MEM USAGE / LIMIT  MEM %       NET IO             BLOCK IO    PIDS        CPU TIME     AVG CPU %

254d65607347  memory_leaking_lxml_container                                   0.09%       164.9MB / 33.29GB  0.50%       40.84MB / 2.479MB  0B / 0B     14          21.501493s   0.84%
```

```
$systemctl status --user container-memory_leaking_lxml_container.service 

● container-memory_leaking_lxml_container.service - Podman container-memory_leaking_lxml_container.service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/shelf/.config/systemd/user/container-memory_leaking_lxml_container.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /run/user/1000/systemd/user.control/container-memory_leaking_lxml_container.service.d
             └─50-MemoryHigh.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-10-26 02:43:46 KST; 13s ago
       Docs: man:podman-generate-systemd(1)
   Main PID: 10403 (conmon)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 202744)
     Memory: 756.0K (high: 1.8G max: 2.0G available: 1.8G)
        CPU: 88ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/container-memory_leaking_lxml_container.service
             └─10403 /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c 6a4a037a7cca7641188ea145446e8fac2ba6a76ccf81ebce7a9d52cb80e31265 -u 6a4a037a7cca7641188ea145446e8fac2ba6a76ccf81ebce7a9d52cb80e31265 -r /usr/bin/crun -b /home/shelf/.local/share/cont>
```

another case is "42.84MB" and "80.9M"

```
af8cfa352332  taskwarrior-webui  0.01%       42.84MB / 12.26GB  0.35%       2.42kB / 430B  0B / 0B     23          959.476ms   0.01%
```

```
[shelf@localhost ~]$ systemctl --user status container-taskwarrior-webui.service 
● container-taskwarrior-webui.service - Podman container-287516d806e5dec732bb2152568304950343e98c75cd05f8ade36826a2d292e2.service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/shelf/.config/systemd/user/container-taskwarrior-webui.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-10-26 01:19:24 KST; 2h 19min ago
       Docs: man:podman-generate-systemd(1)
   Main PID: 1801 (conmon)
      Tasks: 16 (limit: 74601)
     Memory: 80.9M
        CPU: 695ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/container-taskwarrior-webui.service
             ├─1735 /usr/bin/slirp4netns --disable-host-loopback --mtu=65520 --enable-sandbox --enable-seccomp --enable-ipv6 -c -e 3 -r 4 --netns-type=path /run/user/1000/netns/netns-cb5acc65-4f8a-650e-6ae6-68e4fc909e11 tap0
             ├─1738 rootlessport
             ├─1745 rootlessport-child
             ├─1777 /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs -o "lowerdir=/home/shelf/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/l/24YP66TL5NQBZOG6ZSFAGPT42L:/home/shelf/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/l/6OIWR3J24EEIAHQS7UBWPF6XQ4:/home>
             └─1801 /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c af8cfa352332489ffaa29c82efd7ecf6e6dbb0d90705be6b559203a7f45bb8a0 -u af8cfa352332489ffaa29c82efd7ecf6e6dbb0d90705be6b559203a7f45bb8a0 -r /usr/bin/crun -b /home/shelf/.local/shar>

Oct 26 01:19:23 localhost.localdomain podman[1636]: 2023-10-26 01:19:23.144002301 +0900 KST m=+1.152343622 container create af8cfa352332489ffaa29c82efd7ecf6e6dbb0d90705be6b559203a7f45bb8a0 (image=docker.io/dcsunset/taskwarrior-webui:lates>
Oct 26 01:19:24 localhost.localdomain podman[1636]: 2023-10-26 01:19:24.368842932 +0900 KST m=+2.377184246 container init af8cfa352332489ffaa29c82efd7ecf6e6dbb0d90705be6b559203a7f45bb8a0 (image=docker.io/dcsunset/taskwarrior-webui:latest,>
Oct 26 01:19:24 localhost.localdomain systemd[835]: Started Podman container-287516d806e5dec732bb2152568304950343e98c75cd05f8ade36826a2d292e2.service.
Oct 26 01:19:24 localhost.localdomain podman[1636]: 2023-10-26 01:19:24.649773078 +0900 KST m=+2.658114401 container start af8cfa352332489ffaa29c82efd7ecf6e6dbb0d90705be6b559203a7f45bb8a0 (image=docker.io/dcsunset/taskwarrior-webui:latest>
Oct 26 01:19:24 localhost.localdomain podman[1636]: af8cfa352332489ffaa29c82efd7ecf6e6dbb0d90705be6b559203a7f45bb8a0
Oct 26 01:19:46 localhost.localdomain taskwarrior-webui[1801]: 
Oct 26 01:19:46 localhost.localdomain taskwarrior-webui[1801]: > backend@1.0.0 start
Oct 26 01:19:46 localhost.localdomain taskwarrior-webui[1801]: > node ./dist/app.js
Oct 26 01:19:46 localhost.localdomain taskwarrior-webui[1801]: 
Oct 26 01:19:50 localhost.localdomain taskwarrior-webui[1801]: Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```